# "Is it true that <statement>"

Tags: discussion, editing

I've noticed a couple of questions come up recently prefixed with the semantically empty "Is it true that ..."

Such as [Is it true that children under 6 can legally ride a bicycle on the sidewalk in Denmark?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89521/is-it-true-that-children-under-6-can-legally-ride-a-bicycle-on-the-sidewalk-in-d) and [Is it true that you can receive emergency care in the UK completely free of charge?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89497/is-it-true-that-you-can-receive-emergency-care-in-the-uk-completely-free-of-char)

In my view the former question would be better expressed as “Can children under six legally ride a bicycle on the sidewalk in Denmark?”

This removes the suggestive bias in the question (especially to those seeing only the question in a page of search results); it brings the salient issue closer to the front of the sentence; it removes unecessary verbiage which may be needlessly confusing for our many visitors who have trouble corresponding in English; and it makes the URL more descriptive (as it is presently truncated).

Against that is, I think, only the fair view that we should avoid tampering with questions.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

As an author of one of the linked questions - go ahead and edit it. In total we have [17 such questions](https://www.google.cz/search?q=site:travel.stackexchange.com+intitle:%22is+it+true%22&espv=2&ei=W3DAWOGWOIqhsgGcsYWgAg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1856&bih=1014) - feel free to update them too, for better readability.

Comment: Why are people on this Stack Exchange so obsessed with editing old posts to conform to their personal preferences about the English language? I really haven't seen this on any other site that I participate in. Editing "Is it true that X can do Y" to "Can X do Y" has negligible benefit.

Comment: @DavidRicherby because unlike many other sites, the target audience of Travel.SE often has poor command of the English language and rely on Google Translate and/or badly formulated Google queries. And, hey, if people are willing to spend their time on improving the site - why not?

Comment: Google translate seems to handle "Is it true that, ...?" just fine. Google searches will be looking at the keywords X and Y rather than the precise grammatical format of the question around them. This is purely a matter of English style and has almost nothing to do with readability.

Answer (score 2):

This happens a lot on Skeptics.SE. I think the reasons for prefixing it are understandable (eg not wanting to appear to be stupid), but I think the titles should be edited for clarity and conciseness.

Comment: Skeptics is a bit different I think ... there people are often coming with a position they want discredited or affirmed. Here hopefully we are answering questions directly.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not make this kind of edit. The increase in readability is negligible and the cost is flooding the homepage.

This is not a good reason to edit and I would reject any such edit as "No improvement whatsoever" if it appeared in the review queue (which it wouldn't, since you have enough rep to make edits by fiat).